# Xamarin forms: Listview scrollbar showing on the left side

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, scrollbar

I have added following codes for `reversing` the listview(first item on bottom). Normally in xamarin listview, the first item is on the top and remaining items are showing on the bottom of that. I just reverse that feature, the first item will be on the bottom and remaining items are on the top of that(Using the above codes). Now the bottom of my ListView is at the top.

In the ListView set following two properties:

```
FlowDirection=”RightToLeft”
Rotation=”180″
```

And in the view cells main layout:

```
FlowDirection=”LeftToRight”
Rotation=”180″
```

**After that my scrollbar showing on the left side and mouse scrolling behaves opposite of the normal behavior(on UWP). Also, scrolling is not smooth. How can I fix these issues?**

I got the above codes from [this](https://www.xamboy.com/2018/07/09/exploring-a-chat-ui-in-xamarin-forms-part-2/#Rotate%20the%20list) blog. Please see the **Rotate the list** section. In the blog itself, they are telling about the scroll bar on the left side issue and suggested to add `FlowDirection` property to solve this.

**Complete Code:**

```
 <ListView 
      FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
      Rotation="180"
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <ViewCell>
               <ViewCell.View>
                  <StackLayout
                     FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
                     Rotation="180"> 
                     //Listview items
                  </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell.View>
             </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
```

Comment: Try ItemTemplate for the chat.

Comment: @Jaymin Didn't get what you mean?

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/selector and for the chat https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/app-monkeychat